# Match unique id's on import- csv to sql

Tags: mysql, import, csv

I have a csv file that I would like to import into a phpMyAdmin database (Wordpress). The CSV file is formatted as shown below:

```
list-id | post_title    | slider                                  | default-image
5595    | Golden Nugget | http://images.travelnow.com/058883A.jpg | False
5595    | Golden Nugget | http://images.travelnow.com/058883B.jpg | False
5595    | Golden Nugget | http://images.travelnow.com/058883C.jpg | False
5595    | Golden Nugget | http://images.travelnow.com/058883D.jpg | true
```

The current roadblocks are matching posts with their unique ids' (list-id), and having each row overwriting the last. This is how I would prefer the URLs to be formatted for the slider custom field.

```
http://images.travelnow.com/058883A.jpg|http://images.travelnow.com/058883B.jpg|http://images.travelnow.com/058883C.jpg|http://images.travelnow.com/058883D.jpg
```

Any help on importing csv's to sql would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not keep the structure you have and write each jgp url on its own row? You can add a auto_increment `tablename_id` and make the `(list_id, slider)` unique - so you don't have the same slider in the same list twice. Keeping comma (or `|`) separated values in database is never ok.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube, this went straight over my head. Are you able to explain `auto_increment` and how to import this to the database?